# How my book and my python have different values on this "set" variable?

Tags: python

so, in my book state that:

```
dict1 = {'satu': 100, 'dua': 100, 'tiga': 100, 'empat':200}
set1 = set(dict1)
set1
{'tiga', 'dua' 'empat' 'satu'}
```

and while i try it, the code says:

```
dict1 = {'satu': 100, 'dua': 100, 'tiga': 100, 'empat':200}
set1 = set(dict1)
set1
{'satu', 'dua' 'empat' 'tiga'}
```

am i mising something?
[My code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRzFf.png)[text]
[Book Code description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmbKJ.png)

Comment: my book is using python 3.6 for refrence, sorry i forgot to mention it before.

Comment: Order of the elements in set can change. So you can not expect elements to appear in the same order as they are in book. Main point to note is that set has unique elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) it clearly says that:

> A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements.

So the order doesn't count, the only thing that matters, in your case, is that the elements of the set are the same as the ones displayed in the book.

Comment: thank you sir i appreciate it. i will proceed to the next chapter now

Comment: @RazaFreza remeber to upvote/accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Order of the elements in set can change. So you can not expect elements to appear in the same order as they are in book. Main point to note is that set has unique elements.

Comment: ahh i see, so nothings wrong with it.